# Bash: substring from first occurrence of a character to the second occurrence

Tags: string, bash, substring, character, find-occurrences

In bash, how do I get a substring of everything from the first occurrence of a character to the second occurrence of the same character.

Example...

> Input String = "abc-def-ghi"
>
> Character = "-"
>
> Desired Output String = "def"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible use awk with `-` delimiter

```
echo "abc-def-ghi" | awk -F'-' '{print $2}'
```

**-F** - what field separator to use.

**{print $2}** - print second position

Answer (score 11):

I would use two parameter expansions.

```
str="abc-def-ghi"
tmp=${str#*-}  # Remove everything up to and including first -
result=${tmp%%-*} # Remove the first - and everything following it
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have:

```
s="abc-def-ghi"
ch='-'
```

Using BASH `read` builtin:

```
IFS="$ch" read -ra arr <<< $s && echo "${arr[1]}"
```

Or, using BASH regex:

```
re="$ch([^$ch]*)$ch"

[[ $s =~ -([^-]*)- ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

**Output:**

```
def
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use *cut* command like this:

> str="abc-def-ghi"
>
> echo $str | cut -f 2 -d "-"

, where -d option is a delimiter and -f option stands for fragment number (the first fragment number is 1, not 0 as it is common for arrays).